# I am unable to populate files from one folder

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, directory

I am poplulating files from two different folders and sorting according to the filename. but i am not able to populate from one specified folder. Why its like that. i guess there is some error i am doing. Please help me out.

My code snippet:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Initialize Directory path
        string draft = ini.ReadValue("Location", "Draft");
        string release = ini.ReadValue("Location", "Release");
        string drawing = ini.ReadValue("Location", "Drawing");//<<-- Unable to populate this location to the gridview.. Its taking the files from above location..
        string[] arrDraft = Directory.GetFiles(draft, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        string[] arrRelease = Directory.GetFiles(release, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        string[] arrDrawing = Directory.GetFiles(release, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        dt.Columns.Add("Part Number");
        dt.Columns.Add("Drawing");
        dt.Columns.Add("Draft Path");
        dt.Columns.Add("Release Path");
        dt.Columns.Add("Comment");
        dt.Columns.Add("Error");


        List<FileDetails> lst = new List<FileDetails>();
        foreach (string file in arrDraft)
        {
            Finder finder = new Finder(Path.GetFileName(file).Substring(0, 7));
            string abc = Array.Find(arrRelease, finder.Match);
            string def = Array.Find(arrDrawing, finder.Match);//<<--- Here is the mistake i guess i am doing
            dt.Rows.Add(Path.GetFileName(file), def, file, abc, String.Empty, String.Empty);
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    // Search predicate returns true if a string ends in "saurus".
    private static bool MatchFileName(String s, String _match)
    {
        return ((s.Length > 5) && (s.Substring(0, 7).ToLower() == _match.ToLower()));
    }

  public class FileDetails
    {
        public string FileName;
        public string Drawing;
        public string FilePathDraft;
        public string FilePathRelease;
        public string Comment;
        public string ErrorMsg;
    }
    public sealed class Finder
    {
        private readonly string _match;

        public Finder(string match)
        {
            _match = match.ToLower();
        }

        public bool Match(string s)
        {
            string fileName = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            return ((fileName.Length > 5) && (fileName.Substring(0, 7).ToLower() == _match));
        }
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be with the `string name` `drawing`. You have given both `realease` thats why its showing like that.

Please replace the drawing code with

```
 string[] arrDrawing = Directory.GetFiles(drawing, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

All set...!!!

Comment: @StacyKebler always make sure of variable names!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this line

```
string[] arrDrawing = Directory.GetFiles(release, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Should be

```
string[] arrDrawing = Directory.GetFiles(drawing, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```